# How do I make a Word 2010 template available to all users with an MSI installer?

Tags: templates, ms-word, word-2010

I am building an MSI installer for a Word 2010 add-in to be installed for all users. This add-in includes a template that my add-in requires to work. I set the template file to be installed to a common folder, `C:\Program Files\Common\Microsoft\Templates`. I then set the following key:

```
User/Machine Hive: Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\General
  SharedTemplates="[CommonFilesFolder]Microsoft\Templates"
```

When I choose to install for "Just me", the above key and value is loaded into HKEY_CURRENT_USER and all is well. However, when I choose "Everyone", the above key is loaded into HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (like it should), but Word doesn't seem to pick up the value from the registry in that location.

I need to find a way to have the shared templates available to all users when the MSI is installed once for "everyone".

The installer is being run on Windows XP, 32-bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a misunderstanding. 
The distinction between HKCU and HKLM applies to the add-in key ("add-ins loading just for the current user or for all users"). Relative to the "Common\General\Shared Templates" path Word ignores anything from the HKLM hive of the registry. This settings is solely read from HKCU.

In an enterprise environment, usually this setting is distributed via group policy. Word reads first the "Policy" path in HKCU and applies this setting before the one the user can change through the interface.

If your add-in must is installed "for every user", it needs an administrative install, so you may tell the administrator that he has to assure the correct "Workgroup templates" path for all users.

Alternatively, you may try to set up the path on the startup of your add-in, but I'm afraid that a Word reboot is necessary for that the new template path "catches" in Word.

Comment: Frustrating that Word won't read this setting from HKLM, but I guess it makes sense. Thank you for the good answer!